# Self terminating AWS ECS fargate task

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm working on a service which will scan the given file. I'm using the ECS Fargate task for that. ECS task will keep scanning given files and if malware is found, it will perform the required action on that file and terminate itself. To terminate the task, I'm using `System.exit(0)`. Few months back, it was working well. It was terminating the task and Fargate service was creating another task to handle the load. Yesterday I noticed that `System.exit(0)` is not terminating the task any more. Its just exiting from my java application. I could still see java process by using `ps -eaf` command.

I tried using `System.exit(1)` which restart the main method instead of terminating the task.

I tried killing the java process manually in an ECS task using command `kill -9`. But it starts the java process again with a different process id (but not triggering the main method again).

Not sure what has changed again. I'm pretty much sure it was working before.

Terminating the task is the security requirement and we don't have an option to skip that.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECS isn't restarting your Java process inside the container. That is something that is being done by software that is configured inside your docker container. It sounds like you have some sort of startup script you are using as the ECS container's `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`, and that script has changed recently to catch the Java exit and restart the process, instead of just letting the process exit.

All AWS (ECS/Fargate) knows is that it has started a docker container based on the image you gave it, and the primary process of the docker container has not exited yet. If your Java app is being started by some sort of wrapper script, then that script is the primary process, and until that script exits the container will continue to run.

Comment: You are right. I have two entry points. One to start the scanner and another to start a java application. Since docker doesn't allow multiple entry points, I used supervisord. Now supervisord is starting the java application again and again. Now I need to find out a way to handle supervisord or find another way to create multiple entry points.

Comment: Just use a shell script as the entry point. First it can start the scanner as a background process, and then finally it can run the Java process directly.

Answer (score 0):

As I described in thread : [Stopping AWS ECS Fargate task when docker container stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57444375/stopping-aws-ecs-fargate-task-when-docker-container-stops/76388030#76388030) You need to use **((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();** insteed System.exit(0)